# Delete duplicate rows using Analytical functions

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, rows, analytical

Can we delete duplicate rows using analytical functions? I mean using `row_number()` or `rank` or dense_rank() in Sql query in Oracle?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking for. Try writing the query you'd like to work, and post it here (with any error message if you get one), that way people will have a better idea of exactly what you want.

Comment: The answer to this question is: "Yes". Maybe someone could be a bit more helpful and provide a more thoroug explanation if you could explain what you're trying to do as Mat has suggested.

Comment: I am trying to delete duplicate rows. I know the same is possible using rowid in oracl.. Is there any other way??

Comment: Not without making a bigger resource intensive sql statement than needed. Any reason why you really don't want to use the rowid?

Comment: I am just trying to know if this could be done using Analytical functions without rowid!!

Comment: To add to this, you cannot accomplish deleting rows with analytical functions in one single statement. You can do it with multiple statements where you put the unique rows in it's own table. And than replace the current table with this unique data.

Comment: If you have no unique column in your table and rows that are 100% equal, you will need something to identify these rows. Which happens to be `rowid`. Another option would be to add a primary key column to your table, fill it with a sequence and use this to identify your rows.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` over a partition of columns that should be unique for you, e.g: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COLUMN1, COLUMN2 ORDER BY COLUMN1)`. Every result that has a rownumber > 1 is a duplicate.

You can then for example return the rowid's for those and delete them.

Comment: I know how to delete using rowid. However i am searching for a solution without using rowid

Comment: You cannot accomplish deleting rows with analytical functions in one single statement. You can do it with multiple statements where you put the unique rows in it's own table. And than replace the current table with this unique data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  But it could be made a bit simpler with aggregate function

```
-- delete duplicates
delete from table t1
where t1.rowid not in (
   select min(t2.rowid)
   from table t2
   group by t2.col1, t2.col2, ...
)
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a4f02/1)

Comment: i believe that we can't refer `rownum` with alias or with table name like `t1.rownum` as `rownum` is reserved work in `ORACLE`

Comment: we cannot delete using rownum

Comment: @JebySebastian - No more rownums!

Comment: :) @Egor, Is there any other way to do the same??

Comment: @JebySebastian - Pure `delete` statement without using `rowid`s?  I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Analytical Functions` or any other way like `Aggregate Functions` , 'DISTINCT` to find out whether we have duplicates in our table or not

like using `Analytical Functions`

```
select col1,col2,col3 from (select tbl.*,rowid rid,row_number() over (partition by col1,col2,col3 order by col1) rnum
from tbl) where rnum>1;
```

but to delete them we need to get the `ROWID` of those whose `rnum>1`

```
delete from tbl where rowid in 
(select rid from (select tbl.*,rowid rid,row_number() over (partition by col1,col2,col3 order by col1) rnum
  from tbl) where rnum>1)
```

or else we can simply use

```
 create new_table as select distinct * from old_table
```

Comment: I know how to delete using rowid. However i am searching for a solution without using rowid.

Comment: without using rowid i don't think so 
just create a dummy table with distinct values of original table :)

Comment: I am just trying to know if this could be done using Analytical functions without rowid!!

Answer (score 1):

follow these steps to delete duplicate records without using rowid,rownum
1. create table to store distinct values of original table.

```
    create table newtable as select distinct * from tablename;
```

1. delete the records from original table.

   ```
    truncate table tablename;
   ```
2. insert a temporary table values into original table.

   ```
    insert into tablename select * from newtable;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the duplicate rows using this query:

```
DELETE FROM EMP
WHERE ROWID IN
(
SELECT RID FROM
(SELECT ROWID RID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DEPTNO ORDER BY ROWID) R FROM EMP) 
WHERE R>1
);
```

Comment: I doubt that this helps or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please explain this code.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we want to remove duplicate sal from emp table:

```
select * from (
  select 
    empno, 
    ename, 
    sal, 
    row_number() over (partition by sal order by sal asc) rw_number
  from emp)
where rw_number = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM emp 
WHERE rowid IN
(
    SELECT rid from
    (
        SELECT rowid AS rid,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY empno ORDER BY rowid) AS rn
        FROM emp
    )
    WHERE rn > 1
);
```

Here you can use both `RANK()` and `DENSE_RANK()` since both will give unique records when order by `rowid`.

Answer (score -1):

This is the sort of thing you should do:

```
DELETE  FROM emp
WHERE   rowid IN (
        SELECT  rid
        FROM    (
                  SELECT    rowid rid ,
                            DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY empno ORDER BY rowid ) rn
                  FROM      emp
                ) AS RR
        WHERE   rn > 1 );
```

Comment: I doubt that this helps or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please explain this code.